# Is there a special word for purposely misspelling a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking the other day about **Kleenex**, which is purposely misspelled from **clean**-ex, if that makes sense, and I was wondering if there was a word  for purposely misspelling a word, or name.

Comment: Some people might call it a missed-ache.  Others might call it a *pun* ;-)

Comment: Note by the way that Kleene is a surname.

Comment: Brand names that are as well-known as Kleenex frequently become part of the language, as I am sure you realise. Few people in Britain vacuum-clean their homes. Most people 'hoover' them. I don't know if this has any connection to what you are asking, but it is an interesting topic.

Comment: I'd call it marketing.

Comment: If Ex and X mean Formerly, or Not, then Kleenex means "it is not clean" and Timex means "it is not time". There are probably others as well.

Comment: Note that the 'ex' part is actually an abbreviated form of 'tex' which was part of the Kotex trademark where it in turn was an abbreviation of 'textile'. In Kleenex it is just a suffix added to emphasis the product's familial relationship to the manufacturer's existing products. As a suffix developed to enhance their naming policy, I think it is difficult to describe 'ex' as a miss-spelling of anything. https://www.kleenex.com/en-us/faq The letter K is often used in advertising and lends itself to some 'creative misspellings' https://shonaliburke.com/k-is-king-in-brand-and-company-naming/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Deliberate misspelling of words is referred to as ***eye dialect***. It [means](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eye+dialect) use of nonstandard spelling. Examples include *enuff*, *goffik* and *wuz* (for *was*). Another good self-explanatory [term](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/chatspeak) is ***chatspeak*** defined in the Urban Dictioanry as

> Chatspeak, aka netspeak. This is a form of speech in which one shortens words and replaces the letter "s" with the letter "z" in an effort to save time and look cool. Chatspeakers also rarely use capitalization or correct punctuation.

As a general term I recommend ***heterography*** (cf. *orthography*).

> OED: Spelling that differs from that which is correct according to current usage; ‘incorrect’ spelling.

Comment: Though coinage of 'Kleenex' well pre-dates the existence of net chat.

Answer (score 5):

Although most dictionaries simply define it as *[bad spelling](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cacography?q=cacography)*, other sources define [*cacography*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cacography) as *deliberate* misspelling, often for comic effect.

Answer (score 1):

How about : Cacography is deliberate comic misspelling, a type of humour similar to malapropism.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. We are looking for longer answers that include references and citations. If you need assistance in framing an answer, please visit our [Help Page on "How to write an answer"](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)