# Is there a word which describes terms that are spelled like a particular pronunciation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Some examples:
"never" might be written as "neva"

"I don't know" is sometimes written as "iono" or "I dunno" on various internet media.

My question is: is there a word for this particular technique of spelling a term in the way it is (sometimes) pronounced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it called when words are deliberately spelled incorrectly but pronunciation is kept unchanged?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46101/what-is-it-called-when-words-are-deliberately-spelled-incorrectly-but-pronunciat) /////// also [**this**](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/137922/365490)

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul not quite, because these aren't deliberately changed to match the pronunciation. For example Night -> Nite is still pronounced the same way. In a sense it's the opposite of what I was looking for, changing the spelling to match a common pronunciation of a word. The answer below seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's called **eye dialect:**

> Eye dialect is the use of deliberately nonstandard spelling to emphasize how a word is being pronounced. The term was coined by George Philip Krapp to refer a literary technique that implies the standard pronunciation of a given word that is not well-reflected by its standard spelling, such as wimmin to more accurately represent the typical English pronunciation of women. However, eye dialect is also commonly used to indicate that a character's speech is vernacular (nonstandard), foreign, or uneducated. This form of nonstandard spelling differs from others in that a difference in spelling does not indicate a difference in pronunciation of a word. That is, it is dialect to the eye rather than to the ear.
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_dialect)

(The opposite, pronouncing a word as it is spelled, is called **[spelling pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_pronunciation)**)

Comment: And if you are trying to indicate a nonstandard pronunciation, you can call it *pronunciation spelling*. Yes, it's used both ways around to mean two different things. From DARE: "Pronunciation-spellings are those in which a writer tries to represent the nonstandard pronunciation of a speaker."